# Allowing Flash to access the clipboard

Tags: 11.04, firefox, flash, clipboard

I use cacoo.com that is developed in Flash (a tool to make diagrams).

Running it in Windows works fine. But in Ubuntu, it seems that it can't access the system clipboard, blocking actions like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>,<kbd>V</kbd>, etc., which I believe need to access the system clipboard.

So, how can I give permission to Flash to be able to do that? I think that would fix the problem.

I'm running Ubuntu 11.04, and I just installed it. Firefox is the latest version. Adobe Flash plugin version 10.

Comment: Works for me on this page : http://activeden.net/item/simple-text-editor/22783 and there is no settings in Flash Properties for that.

Comment: I have the same problem. @NyamiouTheGaleanthrope, try acessing the clipboard at sliderocket.com.

Answer (score 1):

This is a limitation of Firefox (I'm not sure why they do not allow it). Try using Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

If flash has access to the clipboard, then a web page can for example capture passwords being copied from lastpass.  Allowing webpages access to the clipboard is really not something you want to do.

There are ways to make this safe.  Eg if it's the browser that accesses the clipboard, and it generates an event when you hit ctrl-v, and then passes the clipboard content to only the page, flash app, or whatever that has the keyboard focus, then that's reasonably safe.  If flash initiates the collection of clipboard content though, then that's dangerous.

I'd be wary of any browser or operating system that allows flash access to the clipboard.  Not that it can't be done safely, but I'd want to check on the details.

--

reply to comment below:

Given that the OP specifically refers to ctrl-v and ctrl-v, you're probably right. If it was a paste button in flash, that would definitely be a sign of a security issue though.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the question. The OP is trying to paste clipboard contents himself into the Flash application. It is different from Flash directly accessing the clipboard. :) I do agree with your points if that was indeed the question though.